# How to set fontsize in javascript print() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
function printData()
{
    var divToPrint=document.getElementById("myprinttd");

    document.getElementById("myprinttd").style.fontSize = "2px";

   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}
```

I am using above function to print screen. I want to make the font size small and reduce spaces between the data but i cant. Any one can help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason why your printout might look differently than you expect is that besides the `fontSize` attribute that you are correctly setting, other parent elements and their CSS rules affect the appearance of the element.

`outerHTML` only captures the style that is directly attached to the selected element and thus some style information might get lost.